# It's possible write data in Microstrategy?

Tags: microstrategy

I don't know how to use Microstrategy to write to my database

I would like to know if it's possible (in Microstrategy) to display a report or dossier in which the end user can write in a field. For example, check a box, as if it were a form to write to the database.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The feature you need to use is named "Transaction Services" and can be found in the [documentation](https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/AdvancedReportingGuide/WebHelp/Lang_1033/Content/Creating_a_Transaction_Services_report.htm) and forums using this name.
There are several parts for this feature to work:

1. Users/Security, Your user has to have the correct permissions to create and use the transaction (best to use Workstation and search for "transaction" in permission screen)
2. SQL-Report/Mechanics, Create Freeform SQL Report

   - You can have in and outgoing objects like metrics and attributes here,, both defined on the fly (aka freeform objects) and using project objects.
   - Gotcha: you have to have a outgoing object, use a dummy freeform metric if you don't care about the result
3. Interface/Input, Add the freeform report to a Document or a Dossier.

   - Documents and Dossier transactions don't have the same features, with Documents being the more flexible regarding transaction services.
   - Dossier, only possible with modern grid when using Workstation or when accessing through Library-Editor. Only grid transactions allowed at the moment.
   - Document, here you can enable transactions on Panel-Stacks or Grids in edit mode.

This is only a rough rundown of the things needed, the docs should provide further info for all the little details. Like how to select from an existing report/attribute, input field, grid field etc.